# Move methods out of a React component, but still access the state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to refactor a rather unwieldy React component by moving some methods into a `FooHelpers.js` ES6 class, and then generalising them to work with other, related, React components.

My issue is that these methods I want to move out access the state object of the surrounding React component.

Current situation:

```
// Foo.jsx

getItems() {
    return this.state.items;
}

someLogic() {
    const items = this.getItems();
}
```

Where I'd like to be:

```
// FooHelpers.js

getItems() {
    // ???
}

// Foo.jsx

someLogic() {
    const items = FooHelpers.getItems();
}
```

There are multiple ways I can think about doing this, but I was interested to see if anyone has approached it in a more React-y way.

Comment: Well, the easiest way that I could imagine would be to use `.call`, which I'm sure you've though of already.

Comment: @Nick Nope, didn't think of that at all. Was completely overthinking it :( will leave the question open in case anyone chimes in!

Comment: Best to make your functions stateless. Pass in parts of state and then bind the result back to state. Best way IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for a higher order component who's children will be the components related to your Foo.jsx. See more regarding HoCs in my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729203/4190422.