# Temporarily revert context in JavaScript class method

Tags: javascript

I have this situation:

```
// foo.js

export class Foo {

    fetch() {
        // blah
    }

    getStuff() {
        let stuff = this.fetch(); // call this in the context of Foo, not Bar
    }
}

// bar.js

import {
    Foo
}
from 'Foo.js';
const foo = new Foo();

class Bar {
    test() {
        foo.getStuff.call(this); // needs to be called in the context of Bar
    }
}
```

How exactly can I call `fetch` in the original context of the Foo instance, and not in the Bar instance?

Comment: What `Bar` instance? I can't really make out what the last three lines are supposed to be. You cannot have `this` refer to two different objects... I also don't think this is any specific to ES6. `this` and function calls pretty much work the same way as in ES5.

Comment: What is bar? A class instance or a function? It's not clear from your code because some of it appears to be missing (the code as-is has a syntax error).

Comment: @samsonthehero made some edits!

Comment: *"How exactly can I call fetch in the original context of the Bar instance, and not in the Foo instance?"* Well, you *are* calling `foo.getStuff` in the context of `Bar`, so I'm not sure what else you want to know...

Comment: Well what is it about the code you've got (with the use of `.call()`) that doesn't work?

Comment: @FelixKling Sure, but once within Bar, how can I call `fetch`?

Comment: `this.fetch();` would call `Bar.prototype.fetch`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @FelixKling That is what I want, yes. Just wasn't connecting the dots...thank you.

Comment: Wait, now you are saying that `this.fetch` should call `Foo.prototype.fetch`, even though `this` refers to `new Bar()`? *edit:* yeah

Comment: @FelixKling I'm so sorry, I asked my question wrong. `this.fetch` will refer to `Bar`, not `Foo`, correct? I need it to refer to Foo

Comment: @FelixKling Yes. Got mixed up creating the question!

Comment: I guess the question now becomes why you are doing `foo.getStuff.call(this);` in the first place. `this` cannot not magically refer to two objects. Maybe (some of) the methods should not be implemented as part of classes in the first place.

Comment: @FelixKling Related to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700779/move-methods-out-of-a-react-component-but-still-access-the-state-object

Comment: Maybe you want to call `foo.getStuff(this)` and in `getStuff` call `this.fetch(obj)` where `obj` is a parameter?

Comment: If the helper methods just need read access to the state, why don't you pass the state as argument to them? Don't use classes to merely organize helper methods. That's what modules are for.

Comment: Universal principle: For any function-calling syntax `a.b()`, once inside `b`, `this` becomes `a`, even if `this` was something else on the outside of that method. I think you just want `foo.getStuff()`, plain and simple. Then, the `this` for `this.fetch()` will be `foo`.

Comment: @FelixKling Absolutely an option, I just figured as it was React, that `state` object could be updated at any point, and my Helpers class wouldn't be aware of that